# Integrability of complex gaussian random matrix model

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, integrable-systems

It is known that the partition function
$$ \mathcal{Z}_1=\int dH e^{-N{\rm Tr}(H^2)}e^{-NV(H)},$$ where the integral is over $N\times N$ hermitian matrices $H$, with the potential $$ V(H)=\sum_{j\ge 1}\frac{t_j}{j}{\rm Tr}(H^j),$$ is related to an integrable hierarchy of differential equations in the $t$ variables. This can be reduced to eigenvalues as
$$ \mathcal{Z}_1\propto\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \Delta^2(x)\prod_j e^{-Nx_j^2}e^{-NV(x_j)},$$ where $\Delta(x)$ is the Vandermonde.

Suppose now I change this in the following way
$$ \mathcal{Z}_2=\int dM e^{-N{\rm Tr}(MM^\dagger)}e^{-NV(MM^\dagger)},$$ where $M$ is not hermitian and $V$ is the same as above. This can also be reduced to eigenvalues as
$$ \mathcal{Z}_2\propto\int_0^\infty dx \Delta^2(x)\prod_j e^{-Nx_j}e^{-NV(x_j)}.$$

The question is: is $\mathcal{Z}_2$ also related to an integrable hierarchy?

Comment: can you specify the differential equations you have in mind?

Comment: @AdrienHardy The function $\mathcal{Z}_1$ is related to the so-called KP hierarchy (for Kadomtsev-Petviashvili)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This model is sometimes referred to as the "complex matrix model." The partition function is known to be a tau-function of the forced Toda chain hierarchy and, as a consequence, solves the KP hierarchy.

Comment: This one?: http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9203043v1.pdf

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: @AHusain As far as I remember this one does not consider the complex matrix model. However, the integrable properties of the complex matrix model are closely related to the properties of the Hermitian matrix model, thus, one can use the same approach.

Comment: I don't know a good reference, however, idea of the proof of the Toda integrability for the complex matrix model is the same as for the Hermitian matrix model. Namely, you can represent a partition function as a determinant 
$$ {\mathcal Z}_2 =det_{i,j=1}^N A_{ij}$$
of the matrix of the form
$$A_{ij}=\frac{\partial^{i+j-2} }{\partial t_1^{i+j-2}} A$$
where
$$A=\int_{0}^\infty dxe^{-Nx-NV(x)}.$$